# How to create and populate an activex combobox using vba in excel.

Tags: excel, combobox, vba

I am having a problem when trying to create and then populate a activex combobox in vba for excel. The code below works when run as two seperate macros but when I try to put the two together an empty combobox is created. Can anybody tell me why this is and how to overcome this problem?

Thanks in advance,
JW

```
 Sub CreateComboBox1()
    'Creating ComboBox1:
    ActiveSheet.OLEObjects.Add(ClassType:="Forms.ComboBox.1", _
                Link:=False, DisplayAsIcon:=False, Left:=50, Top:=80, Width:=100, _
                Height:=15).Select
    End Sub

    Sub PopulateComboBox1()
    'Populating ComboBox1
    Sheet1.ComboBox1.AddItem "Date", 0
    Sheet1.ComboBox1.AddItem "Player", 1
    Sheet1.ComboBox1.AddItem "Team", 2
    Sheet1.ComboBox1.AddItem "Goals", 3
    Sheet1.ComboBox1.AddItem "Number", 4
    End
```

Answer (score 5):

Try this

```
Sub CreateComboBox1()
    With ActiveSheet.OLEObjects.Add(ClassType:="Forms.ComboBox.1", _
                Link:=False, DisplayAsIcon:=False, Left:=50, Top:=80, Width:=100, _
                Height:=15)
        With .Object
            .AddItem "Date"
            .AddItem "Player"
            .AddItem "Team"
            .AddItem "Goals"
            .AddItem "Number"
        End With
    End With
End Sub
```