# ActiveX combo box with dynamically-chosen list

Tags: excel, vba, combobox, activex

I was looking at this question:[How to create and populate ActiveX combo box](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11692816/how-to-create-and-populate-an-activex-combobox-using-vba-in-excel)

And I was wondering, how can be implemented when the list of items comes from a range and how to specify in which cell the list should be placed.

Morever, could be nice to have a range of values coming from two different sheets.

```
Sub CreateComboBox1()
    With ActiveSheet.OLEObjects.Add(ClassType:="Forms.ComboBox.1", _
                Link:=False, DisplayAsIcon:=False, Left:=50, Top:=80, Width:=100, _
                Height:=15)
        With .Object
            .AddItem "Date"
            .AddItem "Player"
            .AddItem "Team"
            .AddItem "Goals"
            .AddItem "Number"
        End With
    End With
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tweaked your code a bit to clean it up. Avoid using `ActiveSheet` and use explicit references to the worksheet you're interested in, instead. Also you should store your objects into variables:

```
Option Explicit

Sub CreateComboBox1()

Dim sht As Worksheet
Dim cb As ComboBox
Dim sourceRange As Range
Set sht = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Name of your worksheet")
Set sourceRange = sht.Range("A1:A10") 'example source range

Set cb = sht.OLEObjects.Add(ClassType:="Forms.ComboBox.1", Link:=False, DisplayAsIcon:=False, Left:=50, Top:=80, Width:=100, Height:=15).Object
cb.List = sourceRange.Value

End Sub
```

Basically you can use the `.List` property to specify the source range.

Another way to do it would be to use a `For-Each` loop, to loop through the items you want to add to the list. This way you can add to the list, the items of two different ranges from different sheets:

```
Option Explicit

Sub CreateComboBox1()
Dim cell As Range
Dim sht1 As Worksheet
Dim sht2 As Worksheet
Dim cb As ComboBox
Dim sourceRange1 As Range
Dim sourceRange2 As Range

Set sht1 = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Name of your worksheet 1")
Set sht2 = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Name of your worksheet 2")
Set sourceRange1 = sht1.Range("A1:A10")
Set sourceRange2 = sht2.Range("A1:A10")

Set cb = sht1.OLEObjects.Add(ClassType:="Forms.ComboBox.1", Link:=False, DisplayAsIcon:=False, Left:=50, Top:=80, Width:=100, Height:=15).Object

For Each cell In sourceRange1
    cb.AddItem cell.Value
Next cell
For Each cell In sourceRange2
    cb.AddItem cell.Value
Next cell

End Sub
```

Comment: that's the approach I followed:

https://pastebin.com/rK026Czr

the combobox appears but it raises immediately an error on line "Set cb ...":
Error: 438
Surely because Target doensn't have the Left, Top etc properties. how can I refer to the position of the selected cell?

Comment: got it, the problem was in the combined range!
Unfortunately, the combobox selection is not pasted as value cell, is there a wawy to achieve that?

Comment: You can’t just concatenate the address of two ranges belonging to different sheets to get a combined range. Union doesn’t work either across sheets. The way to do it is the one I demonstrated above. You’ll have to loop through the ranges one by one and add their items to the list.